# Counting how often words occur in neighboring of specific words?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am working on an NLP problem that in one part of it i need to count co-occurrence of words beside or in 2-step of each other. Imagine we select a word, i want to check neighboring 2 words forward and 2 words backward of it. For example, suppose we have this sentence: `"depending on the weather, i will go to park if the weather is sunny tomorrow."` then we have a list: `x=[',','i','to']`. For example, for word `'will'` i assume a window of size 4. so the selected words are: `',','i','go','to'`. Then i check to see if these words are in my list x.And i should do this for all of the words in the sentence except ords that are in list. This concept is very close to finding `n-grams` and `TrigramCollocationFinder` in `nltk` but it is not the exact thing that i want. the below picture show what i really want.

Is there any library or function that i can use to solve my problem (from NLTK for Scikit?)? Can anyone give the idea of implementing it?

[image]

Comment: @dennlinger  thank you so much. it is very close to my answer. i can use the answers to solve my problem. thank you

Comment: No worries, I know how hard it can be to find the exact wording in order to get to the right existing question/answer :) Glad I could help!